# SQLPS tab completion is very slow

Tags: sql-server, powershell, sqlps

SQLPS tab expansion (tab completion) is so slow, it is completely unusable.  Is there something wrong with my configuration?  Is there a later version I should somehow upgrade to?  Is there some kind of fix that would make this usable?

Relevant version info:

- Windows7 64-bit
- SQL Server 2008
- SQL Server Management Studio 10.0.5512.0
- SQLPS.exe FileVersion (10.0.1600.22 ((SQL_PreRelease).080709-1414 )
- sqlps, $psversiontable:

  - CLRVersion: 2.0.50727.5466
  - BuildVersion: 6.1.7601.17514
  - PSVersion: 2.0

Answer (score 1):

As near as I can tell, the performance problem is actually in the implementation of Resolve-Path in the SqlServer psprovider.  Resolve-Path is how the default implementation of TabExpansion (in Powershell v2) does path completion.

I was able to work around this problem by overriding the TabExpansion function to use Get-ChildItem and Where-Object instead of Resolve-Path.  You can [find the latest implementation in this bitbucket repo](https://bitbucket.org/kberridge/posh-prefs/src/743f7840c3789ce319fced0fc2d2e7507de273d4/Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.PowerShell.sqlps_profile.ps1?at=default).

Here's the current implementation:

```
function TabExpansion($line, $lastWord) {
  if (!((get-location).Provider.Name -eq "SqlServer")) {
    TabExpansionSqlPsBackup $line $lastWord
  }
  else {
    $index = $lastWord.LastIndexOfAny(@('\', '/'))
    if ($index -gt -1) { 
      $parent = $lastWord.substring(0, $index+1) 
      $leaf = $lastWord.substring($index+1)
    }
    else {
      $parent = ""
      $leaf = $lastWord
    }

    $matches = ls -path $parent | ?{ $_.PSChildName -match "^$leaf" }
    if ($matches) { 
      $matches | %{ $parent + $_.PSChildName } 
    } 
    else {$lastWord}
  }
}
```

Put that function in the sqlps profile file located at ~\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.PowerShell.sqlps_profile.ps1